# Monitor RBAC access

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I need to tighten RBAC for already deployed CRD in Kuberenets.
I am wondering can I drop all existing roles and bindings, then monitoring the forbidden access.

Unfortunately the kube-apiserver has no audit log settings, and if possible I would like to avoid modifying statically installed kube-apiserver.

So far I tried to get the information from apiserver **metrics** and **logs**.

1. The metrics contains only 200 and 404 requests, 403 is missing and has no information about nor the caller, nor the verb is matching with k8s terms, what is important. `{code="404",component="apiserver",contentType="application/json",endpoint="https",group="networking.k8s.io",instance="123.123.123.123:6443",job="apiserver",namespace="default",resource="ingresses",scope="resource",service="kubernetes",verb="GET",version="v1"}`
2. The logs seems verbose, but not much useful information. At least far from what I would expect from an http server

Answer (score 0):

Droping all the roles and respective bindings is a high-risk operation thatcan  potentially lock out authorized or known users from accessing resources. It is highly recommended to proceed with caution and have a backup plan in case of unintended consequences.

You can use log server (e.g. [Graylog server](https://graylog.org/), [Elastic stack kubernetes](https://www.elastic.co/elastic-stack), etc.) to export logs and further analyze and study the behavior of your cluster.

On the other hand, you can use [Falco](https://falco.org/) to check your cluster's security integrity and [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/) to assist you on applying RBAC configurations. These are CNCF projects that are open-source. There can be other products you may use other than the mentioned applications that are open-source projects as well.